# Extracting and saving characters from an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I am following up from this post: [How to extract only characters from image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971769/how-to-extract-only-characters-from-image)

This solution works perfectly for me (with some tweaking) for its desired purpose. However, I am attempting to take it 1 step further by saving each of the characters. So in the example of this post, I wish to save the characters `K`, `N`, and `M` as their own individual images. I attempted  iterating through the nested if loop with a `cv2.imwrite` function with the rect object although the final output is 7 images containing the overall image with just an additional rectangle to highlight the next contour each time.

[image: example image:]

Comment: Can you add an example sample image?

Comment: @nathancy yes of course, I have now edited it in. In this image case it would only be 3 images as opposed to 7

Comment: That looks perfect at just a glance, I'll have an attempt at that. Thank you very much!

Comment: If that link didn't work for you, take a look at the solution I posted below

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, grayscale, [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization)
2. **Extract ROIs.** [Find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)
   and sort from left-to-right to ensure we have the contours in the correct order with [`imutils.contours.sort_contours`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7). We filter using [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) then extract and save each ROI using Numpy slicing.

---

Input

[image]

Binary image

[image]

Detected characters highlighted in green

[image]

Extracted ROIs

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
from imutils import contours

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Find contours, sort from left-to-right, then crop
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts, _ = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")

# Filter using contour area and extract ROI
ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 10:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hi nathancy, I know my this comment will be removed by the moderators. But before it gets can you please suggest me some resources to learn opencv, I see your answer nowadays in most of OCV question. And I am a beginner can you please help me out with this.